# Why is "$.ajax({" refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert an email address into my db with an ajax call.
Here comes the problem. Instead of working into the background, it refreshes the page.

`alert("yea");` in the success function is not being reached.

What could be the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#header-subscribe").click(function(){
        var str = $("#email").val();        
      if( validateEmail(str)) {

        $.ajax({

      url: 'php/signupForm.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'email='+str,
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        alert("yea");
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }

    });
```

The form:

```
<form id="hero-subscribe" class="the-subscribe-form" >
     <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="email">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-subscribe" id="header-subscribe" type="submit">subscribe</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're not preventing the default action of the click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ajax call has nothing to do with the refresh. You have a submit button and the purpose of the submit button is to submit the form.

The simplest solution would be to not use a submit button:

```
type="button"
```

---

However, binding the event handler to the click event of the button is not good practice. So instead of that and changing the type, bind the handler to the submit event and [prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) (which is submitting the form):

```
$("#hero-subscribe").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of the click...

```
$("#header-subscribe").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the `submit` event of form and use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of event.

```
$("#hero-subscribe").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault()` the form action, otherwise it submits like a normal form.

```
$("#header-subscribe").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //stop the default submit action
```